# Support France, Suggest Some French Music

Tags: discussion

There isn't really a lot that this community can do to show solidarity with or support for the people of France in this dark hour. However, we can listen to their music, and support their artists.

So if there's a particular song or group that you like, post some information about it in an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm partial to a little [MC Solaar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MC_Solaar) Myself - if you're not averse to Hip Hop, give him a click! e.g. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JSG2qHBm7WM

Answer (score 0):

Most of the music that I listen to is generally in the spectrum of pop/rock. One of the musicians in that spectrum who has done some music I like is [Alizée](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliz%C3%A9e). Especially the songs Moi...Lolita and J'en ai marre!.

Answer (score 0):

He's only half French, but Vladimir Cosma's [Sentimental Walk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lN_8qFinDBM) is one of the highlights of the (very French) film *Diva* for me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm late to this party, but French DJ David Guetta's "[This One's for You](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MoHnffhBwqs)" (alongside the Swedish Zara Larsson) was the anthem for the Euro 2016 football (soccer) championship, held in France.